# Haskell and Ord

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a simple min function that accepts two parameters & returns True if the first must appear before the second in sorted order, False otherwise:

```
min :: a -> a -> Bool
min a b = if a < b then True else False
```

I get:

```
No instance for (Ord a)
arising from a use of `<'
```

Comment: if foo then True else False can always be rewritten as simply foo

Comment: And next time, if you're in doubt, you can simply leave out the type annotation in the top and ask the compiler in many cases. Thus, :t min gives me the correct type with the Ord constraint, when I query ghci about it.

Comment: @Sarah: Sometimes I think it would be a good idea that GHC, on encountering a type error in a declaration with an explicit type signature, tries again without the sig and then provides a message like "Change the declared type of `min` to `Ord a => a -> a -> Bool` to make it work".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a type constraint for `<` to work:

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
--     ^^^^^
```

Comment: It would be helpful to tell them why - what a type constraint is.

Comment: @amindfv: dave4420 already did that and I upvoted his answer.

Answer (score 24):

If you [look at the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#t%3aOrd), you will see that the type for `(<)` is given as

```
(<) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

This is misleading!

The type declaration appears in a typeclass definition:

```
class Eq a => Ord a where ...
```

So the full type is

```
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

Incidentally, if you ask ghci what `(<)`'s type is, it will get it right.

```
Prelude> :t (<)
(<) :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Bool
```

Also note there is already a function called `min`, in the same typeclass.

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
```

So you can't call your function `min` unless you hide the original `min`. (I'm not going to show you how. Use a different name for your function instead.)

---

Finally, you now have

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
min a b = if a < b then True else False
```

As Sarah notes, `if blah then True else False` is the same as `blah`, so you can simplify to the clearer

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
min a b = a < b
```

Now operators in Haskell are just functions with funny names --- this is the same as

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
min a b = (<) a b
```

We can simplify this further:

```
min :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
min = (<)
```

So your `min` is just a different name for `(<)`. Why not simply use the original `<` instead of your `min`?

Comment: +1 nice step-by-step explanation from `min a b = if a < b then True else False` to `<`.

Answer (score 8):

There are already two answers to this, but I think there's an important point missing:

The *reason* that you need `(Ord a) =>` in your type signature is that you need to constrain the types that are allowed "into" your function.

When I define a function `function :: a -> a`, I am saying that my function will take data of **any** type, and return a value of the same type.

A good example of this is `head :: [a] -> a` -- given a list of **any** type, head will return the list's first argument. This is because head doesn't really "touch" the data itself, so it doesn't matter at all what it is.

However, your situation isn't like that: imagine we have a data type Countries:

```
data Countries = USA | Nigeria | China | Canada -- yes, I know there are a few missing
```

It makes no sense to say `min USA Canada` or `USA < Canada`.

Therefore you have to restrict your functions to types which can be compared this way: types which have instances of the `Ord` (meaning ordered) typeclass. The way you restrict them is by writing `(Ord a) =>` before your type signature.